# Java optimal default number of threads without blocking I/O

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, jvm, vert.x

Two of the most common defaults that I've seen when sizing a non-blocking thread pool are:

```
number of threads = number of cores

number of threads = number of cores + 1
```

but now I found another one in [Vert.x](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.java#L34), which is:

```
number of threads = 2 * number of cores
```

Apparently the [logic behind this value](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vertx/Lkjg_CGRtAs/UkxTQW6FhbYJ) is that, as Java has no way of pinning a particular thread to a particular core, if we set `# threads == # cores`, we might be wasting some of the available cores. Theoretically by setting the `# threads` to something like `2 * # cores` the probability of using all the cores increases.

I'm not sure if I'm convinced by this argument, as I would expect the OS scheduler to try to find the best distribution of work across the cores. It might not be the optimal distribution, but I would expect it to be better than having a constant multiplier.

I know that it all depends on the kind of tasks being performed but, assuming there is no blocking IO (so no need to have inactive threads waiting lots of time for a resource), is `2 * # cores` a better default approach than `# cores`? Why?

Comment: I suspect they have hyper-threading turned on which allows you to run two threads on each core simultaneously.

Comment: Then there is the question of how many cores are there really? http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue220.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitive book to Java threads (Java Concurrency in Practice) says:

> For compute-intensive tasks, an Ncpu-processor system usually achieves optimum utilization with a thread pool of Ncpu +1 threads. (Even compute-intensive threads occasionally take a page fault or pause for some other reason, so an "extra" runnable thread prevents CPU cycles from going unused when this happens.)

According to my experiments this is true (Ncpu +1 was slightly better than Ncpu even though there was no I/O, but further increasing the number of threads had no benefits).

Of course, in a concrete situation you should always measure :)

Comment: Re, "...even though there was no I/O.":  The paragraph that you quoted is telling you that there _is_ I/O even when there is "no I/O".  Paging is I/O too.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes. I meant that there was no explicit I/O in the code.

Answer (score 2):

The only definitive answer is to profile each one, because the behavior depends on what's running on your target system as well as the code involved.

If all of the threads are getting equal time, having (2*cores) will cause more context switches which can incur a penalty.

Also slightly related, there *is* a thread affinity library for Java called OpenHFT - which uses native code - allowing you to bind threads to specific cores.